# Procedure returning multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a database which maintains interactions with my application, a log kinds.

I want to generate reports for total interactions per day in a month. What is the best possible way to write a procedure that would return up 30 values, each value representing the count for a day?

I am using SQL Server 2005. I retrieve these values in a .NET code, upon which I want to run my algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: have you stored visit count in any table ? if stored then give your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql query will look like the following.

```
select top 30 DATEPART(day, InteractionDate) as Day, COUNT(1) as Interactions from logTable group by DATEPART(day, InteractionDate)
```

In .NET you can use SqlDataReader and store values in a List

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures often return result sets - what you want here is a simple SELECT statement in your stored procedure.  Depending on what technology you are using, you can use a `SqlDataReader` to get data back into your own structures or `SqlDataAdapter` to grab it all into a `DataSet` object.

So we've broken it down into two tasks: (1) Write a `SELECT` to produce the data you want, (2) Use a DR/DA in the app/service to retrieve it.

evpo gives a good example of the first.